# Can phpunit compare two different objects asserting that their properties are identical?

Tags: unit-testing, object, phpunit, comparator

This following test passes because `true == 1`, but I would like to write a test that fails since `true !== 1`.

```
$stdClass1 = new stdClass();
$stdClass1->foo = true;
$stdClass2 = new stdClass();
$stdClass2->foo = 1;

$this->assertEquals(
    $stdClass1,
    $stdClass2
);
```

The following test fails because the two variables do not reference the same object, but I would like to write a test that passes since `true === true`.

```
$stdClass1 = new stdClass();
$stdClass1->foo = true;
$stdClass2 = new stdClass();
$stdClass2->foo = true;

$this->assertSame(
    $stdClass1,
    $stdClass2
);
```

Therefore, does phpunit offer a native way to compare two different objects asserting that their properties are identical?

I have seen solutions (hacks) which convert the objects into arrays in then use `$this->assertEqualsCanonicalizing()`, or serialize the objects and then use `this->assertEquals()`, and so on. However, these solutions are not ideal for large objects which have properties consisting of a few different data types. Respectively, the canonicalization fails when attempting to convert a data type (such as DateTime to float), or the error message produced after serialization is hundreds of lines long making it tedious to find one difference.

Therefore, does phpunit offer a native way to compare two different objects asserting that their properties are identical?

For now, the only reliable solution we have is to write a specific test for each property. Perhaps this decision by phpunit is deliberate in order to force more robust unit tests.

```
$this->assertSame(
    $stdClass1->foo,
    $stdClass2->foo
);
```

The above test works as desired for the purpose of comparing objects, although we will need to loop through all of our properties and `assertSame` for each one.

Comment: According to the documentation, `assertEqualsCanonicalizing()` looks like it works on objects without converting them to arrays beforehand, though it does convert them to arrays internally.

Comment: I've always had the same problem of comparing objects, I usually compare the object properties one by one, but I didn't have any big object with tons of properties to compare.